# How to perform Crossdomain requests asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is a sample code which is trying to use

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("");
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = @"<XMLRequest>
        <RequestType>Destination</RequestType> 
        <RequestLogin>
        <Username></Username> 
        <Password></Password> 
        </RequestLogin>
        </XMLRequest>";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        return View();
    }
```

*When handling to View you need to send a Post request with the receipt of the response from the server. For a long time already I am
suffering over this decision, but nothing is impossible. Please
help!!! Conditions for obtaining the data: via HTTPS Protocol, method:
POST, MIME-type: multipart/form-data in accordance with RFC1867
(http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt). The request must contain three
parameters:

1. login (string username);
2. password (string PASSWORD);
3. get (list | all | ,,…).*

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, more correctly written question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (not targeting the question): Where do you actually set the post data? I do think you are not setting the data. Just to avoid further problems.

Comment: Over the last 3 days a lot of options were tried, until the desired result is not achieved. On this and asked for help here who share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but in this example you do not put your data at all. Try

```
public async Task<ActionResult> About()
{
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("");
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.Method = "POST";
            string postData = @"<XMLRequest>
            <RequestType>Destination</RequestType> 
            <RequestLogin>
            <Username></Username> 
            <Password></Password> 
            </RequestLogin>
            </XMLRequest>";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            //Set data...
            var dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            await request.GetResponseAsync();
            return View();
}
```

or use FormUrlEncodedContent

```
var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "YourName"),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "YourPassword"),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("get", "list")};

var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("");
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] dataArray = await data.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
request.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

var dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
dataStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

var resp = await request.GetResponseAsync();
dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: The request must contain three parameters: 1) login (string username); 2) password (string PASSWORD); 3) get (list). get=list", the server returns a list of XML documents that are in the Outbox folder for this demonstrator, and the XML format;

Comment: Don't know what you're doing wrong, but the working result was not reached.